# Magento loading very slow in MAMP Pro, 10 times slower than remote instance

Tags: magento-1.9, magento-1.8, debugging

My Magento site is taking about a minute to load each page, but my remote instance, which is the same, loads in a few seconds.

Anything I can find about a similar issue, like [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8963906/why-are-my-mamp-pro-local-dev-sites-slow-in-firefox-chrome), give a solution that is not working for me.

Also, my other sites in MAMP Pro don't have this issue.

Anyone have a suggestion about how to solve this?

Comment: I'm having the exact same problem. Did you ever find a solution?

Comment: No, and ironically, I had forgotten I posted this, and just this instance got frustrated again, tried searching for a solution and found my own post! Funny that you just posted too!

Comment: Someone suggested that it might be an extension. Here: http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/68430/magento-1-9-1-0v4-exact-clone-is-extremely-slow-on-local-machine-only-fronte/68437#68437

Comment: I think I might have fixed it. I turned on dynamic dns in the MAMP settings and turned it off again, and now it is fast. Not sure what that did, but it seems to be working. I will check out that extension too.

Comment: Mine is working since I turned the dynamic dns on and off. Can you try that?

Comment: I never used dynamic dns. Not sure why this should help.

Comment: Dynamic DNS seems to be the answer to this question, worked for me too

Comment: I don't know why this question was closed. This actually worked for me too so it's not opinion based, it's actually a bug in MAMP PRO and this seems to fix it