# Magento 1.9.1.0v4 - exact clone is extremely slow on local machine - only frontend

Tags: magento-1.9, performance

I cloned my server version of a Magento install locally. I changed nothing (besides the base url) and it is extremely slow.  With extremely I mean loading is almost not possible (up to a minute and more). The version on the server is just fine.

This only affects the frontend. The backend works fine.

I run it on a Mac with MAMP Pro with PHP 5.6.2 and MySQL 5.5.38. Machine is a new macbook pro with 16GB RAM and 2,8 GHz Intel Core i7.

PHP config:

```
max_execution_time = 600     
max_input_time = 600    
memory_limit = 512M
```

MySQL config:

```
# The MySQL server
[mysqld]
socket      = /Applications/MAMP/tmp/mysql/mysql.sock
key_buffer = 1024M
max_allowed_packet = 512M
table_cache = 1024
sort_buffer_size = 4096K
net_buffer_length = 512K
read_buffer_size = 4096K
read_rnd_buffer_size = 4096K
myisam_sort_buffer_size = 1024M

log = /Applications/MAMP/logs/mysql_sql.log

[mysqldump]
quick
max_allowed_packet = 256M

[mysql]
no-auto-rehash

[isamchk]
key_buffer = 64M
sort_buffer_size = 64M
read_buffer = 8M
write_buffer = 8M

[myisamchk]
key_buffer = 64M
sort_buffer_size = 64M
read_buffer = 8M
write_buffer = 8M
```

Other sites on this Mac run just fine and fast.

Magento cache is activated and the indexes and the cache are up to date.

What could cause this?

Comment: Is the front-end trying to connect to some sort of external service and timing out?

Comment: I don't think so. My machine is online and connected to the internet, so timeouts shouldn't be an issue...

Comment: Right, but often times, production sites connect to services which cannot be accessed from the outside, or are otherwise limited in some manner. I see that you've resolved your problem, but this may help out someone else in a similar situation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it's only on the front-end it probably has to do with an installed extension.

It's for example possible that you have an extension that uses curl to retrieve data (for example a Twitter feed). If the data source can't be reached, it might take a while before the request times out, causing the page to take a very long time to load.

You can add `<disable_local_modules>true</disable_local_modules>` to your `app/etc/local.xml` in the `general` tag. It will disable all modules in `app/code/local`. Alternatively you can try to disable and re-enable each extension separately, change front-end theme etc.

Also you can try to install a fresh install of Magento and see if you experience the same issue. If not, it must be a custom extension.

If both front and back-end would be slow I'd expect it to be an issue with xDebug or similar.

Comment: Going into app/etc/modules and deactivating all extra extensions that I added did the trick I think. At least it now loads in ~20 sec, which is still painfully slow but much better than before... Oh, and don't forget to clear/rebuild the cache after that.

Comment: Further explanation on how to disable extensions: http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/34244/temporarily-disable-magento-extensions-from-the-back-end

Comment: Good to hear. You can also try to mount the var/cache and var/session in tmpfs memory. 20 seconds seems like a long time, maybe xDebug is enabled by default? It will slow down the system a lot (but is very handy when debugging of course)